# Is there a way to override create method as well as build in factory girl?

Tags: ruby, factory-bot

In factory girl, you can override the build method by specifying an initialize_with block, is there a way to do this with the create method?

It looks like when you call create in factory girl, it internally calls #build, then save!. However, I am using an API/gem backed model, and calling #build then save! will not work, but it does have the concept of persistence. How should I override create for these factories? It would be a lot cleaner than overriding save!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can override `to_create`.  See [Custom Methods For Persisting Objects](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Custom_Methods_to_Persist_Objects) in GETTING_STARTED.

```
factory :different_orm_model do
  to_create { |instance| instance.persist! }
end
```

You can also define a [custom "strategy"](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_girl/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Custom_Strategies), which is what FactoryGirl calls things like `build` and `create`.